# Auditctl custom rules for groups

Tags: centos, linux-audit

I'm running CentOS8 and I have 4 main groups in my system, I'm trying to create a rule that filters file modification by group. Like for example if the group operators changed my php configuration, I want it such that when I search for it using ausearch it will tell me **which file has been modified** and **what they used to modify it**. Currently I am using this rule to check for file changes:

```
-a entry,always -S all -F gid=6450 -k operators #testing for all syscalls
-a entry,always -S open -F gid=6450 -k operators #whenever the group opens a file
```

Where: 6450 is the gid for my Operators group. However, this rule only returns:

> type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(2020-04-06 08:24:07.497:274) : auid=unset
>   ses=unset subj=system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0 op=add_rule
>   key=operators list=exit res=yes

Is there any way for me to add which file is modified and what is used to modify it? Or at least tell me which member of the group changed it. Thanks.